The Byzantine Majority Text and the referent of Acts 20:28
The Byzantine Majority Text of Acts 20:28 contains reference to the Church of both Lord and of God apparently separately, as they are separated by kai.  The text would say something like:

to feed the church of the Lord and of God, which he purchased with his own blood.

The King James version, based on the Textus Receptus, renders the verse:

to feed the church of God, which he hath purchased with his own blood.

The Textus Receptus and the King James translation could seem obvious that the referent of "his own blood" is God.
My question is, in the Byzantine majority text, to which is "his own blood" referring; the Lord or God?
A secondary question, if it is allowed, is why the difference between the two texts?

The State of the Text
The variant in that passage is listed as follows in the CNTTS database:

του θ̅υ̅ 01 03 056 35* 104 614 1175 1505 1611 2147 2412 2495
του κ̅υ̅ P41 P74 02 04* 05 08 044 33 945 1739 1891 2344
του κυριου και θεου  MT

Two of the "great" uncials, Sinaiticus and Vaticanus preserve the reading, "God" (ⲑⲩ). Two of the other 'great' uncials, Sinaiticus and the Ephraemi Rescriptus, along with some papyri witnesses preserve the reading, "Lord" (ⲕⲩ).  The MT preserves both.
How did this come about?
One of the 'canons' of textual criticism is that the best solution is often the one that explains the state of the evidence we have today.  Evidently, in the Majority Text, when they had to decide between two readings, they simply preserved both.  This is a common feature of the Byzantine families of texts: that they preserve the longer readings when given the choice between either a longer or shorter reading. The final reading is this:  “Προσέχετε οὖν ἑαυτοῖς καὶ παντὶ τῷ ποιμνίῳ, ἐν ᾧ ὑμᾶς τὸ πνεῦμα τὸ ἅγιον ἔθετο ἐπισκόπους, ποιμαίνειν τὴν ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ κυρίου καὶ θεοῦ, ἣν περιεποιήσατο διὰ τοῦ ἰδίου αἵματος.” (Acts 20:28 GNT-BYZ).
What/Whom is the referent for "his blood"?
The referent for "his blood" (ⲧⲟⲩⲁⲓⲙⲁⲧⲟⲥⲧⲟⲩⲓ̈ⲇⲓⲟⲩ·) is the Lord (or God, if you go with the other variant).  The "Lord", of course, is the way the LXX translated the Tetragrammaton. And that custom is handed down into NT usage. So the blood refers back to the Lord (or God).
What does this mean?
This then becomes one of the key passages that speaks about the two natures united in the person of the Christ. Jesus is truly God and truly human (ⲉⲛⲁⲛⲑⲣⲱⲡⲏⲥⲁⲛⲧⲁ, as we say in the Nicene Creed). And as such, in the person of the Christ, God spilled his own blood on the cross as he died for the sins of the world (cf. Jn. 1:29, et al.)

So the MT retains both of what are, essentially, synonyms and the kai in between would be copulative rather than a separation?

Assuming the Byz. text isn't defective in that section (which I conclude the opposite), it would be better explained as epexegetical/explanatory, rather than copulative.  I.e. the 2nd word explains & fleshes out the 1st: "The Lord, that is God." A copulative usage would conclude that both God and the Lord spilled blood almost as if there were two entities, which is just awkward.

According to UBS5 we have the following readings in Acts 20:28:
1. "the God"

... ποιμαίνειν τὴν ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ Θεοῦ, ἣν περιεποιήσατο διὰ τοῦ
αἵματος τοῦ ἰδίου = to shepherd the church of the God, which He
purchased with His own blood.

This reading is supported by Sinaiticus, B, 614, 1175, 1409, l60, l592, l589, l603, l1021, l1439, some itala texts, vulgate texts, Syriac texts, Coptic texts, and numerous church fathers.  See UBS5 for more details.
In this reading, "God" clearly refers Jesus as God because we have the article before "God", and, we are also told that this God shed His blood.
2. "the Lord"

... ποιμαίνειν τὴν ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ κυρίου, ἣν περιεποιήσατο διὰ
τοῦ ἰδίου αἵματος = to shepherd the church of the Lord which He
purchased with His own blood.

This reading is supported by: P74, A, C(original), D, E, Psi, 33, 36, 181, 307, 453, 610, 945, 1678, 1739, 1891, 2344, l599, some some itala texts, vulgate texts, Syriac texts, Coptic texts, and numerous church fathers.  See UBS5 for more details.
In this reading we have Jesus referred to as "Lord".  Nothing unusual about that as it is Jesus most common title in the NT.
3. "the Lord and God"
... ποιμαίνειν τὴν ἐκκλησίαν τοῦ κυρίου καὶ θεοῦ, ἣν περιεποιήσατο διὰ τοῦ ἰδίου αἵματος = to shepherd the church of the Lord and God which He purchased with His own blood.
This reading is supported by C(third correction), L, P and the Slavic Lectionary.
The construction τοῦ κυρίου καὶ θεοῦ, is a classic TSKS construction meaning that we have:

a single article followed by two titles
the two titles are connected by "and"

This MUST mean that both titles refer to the same person, namely Jesus.  That is, in this reading, Jesus is referred to as both "Lord" and "God".  See Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics by Wallace.  This is confirmed by the singular (not plural)

relative pronoun ἣν = which
singular verb περιεποιήσατο = He purchased
singular noun αἵματος = blood
singular adjective = His own

Thus, for the text containing τοῦ κυρίου καὶ θεοῦ, = The Lord and God, this refers unambiguously to a single person with two titles.

Thank you. Is it possible for the Holy Ghost to be the referent, or one of the referents?  The Holy Ghost is the subject who made them overseers to tend the church of, etc.

@MikeBorden - that is not possible either grammatically nor semantically: grammatically because "Holy Spirit is too far away and separated from the verb by several other nouns such as overseers, church, etc.  It is also not possible semantically because the Holy Spirit did not shed His own blood.

It's really hard to conclude that Wallace uses this as proof for the Granville Sharp rule when Wallace himself explicitly (p. 276) says that Acts 20:28 should be factored out due to its "dubious textual variant".

@Epimanes - I am not suggesting that Wallace did anything of the kind.  However, IF we accept this variant of the text, then this amounts to a TSKS construction.

@Dottard Again, what kind of "if" is this? This is a contrary to fact "if".  We cannot take a CTF conditional and use it as proof of...anything.  If Wallace has denied that this is a passage that can be used as an example of the Granville Sharp rule, then it is not intellectually honest to use it as such. The TSKS construction is a highly debated one. So you're willing to take a debated construction, based on a dubious text to make an unfounded conclusion? I've seen your work in the past. You can do better than that.

@Epimanes - I am NOT suggesting what you are saying. I am not presenting this as proof of anything. I am simply commenting on the grammar and meaning of each textual variant. Indeed, I agree with Wallace that because textual variant #3 is a minority variant it is unlikely to be the original. However, that does not prevent us discussing the grammar of this variant.  In fact, I agree with the text of NA28 which is variant #1 above.  BUT - the OP's question is about textual variation #3.
